# Repetition of the indefinite article with several nouns

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

Now there's another question for *the repetition of indefinite article with several adjectives*, but my question here is rather about nouns.

Examples:

> She's **a** manager and **a** shareholder.

or

> She's **a** manager and shareholder.

Do we make use of only one indefinite article or add several?

Comment: Or, you could say 'She's both manager and shareholder'. (Using the null article.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lists of two, either works. When the list gets beyond two, it's appropriate to use the latter in a comma separated list.

> She's a manager, shareholder, financier, and senior adviser.